# insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!

Tags: software-installation, updates

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
[sudo] password for meow:
Csomaglisták olvasása... Kész
Függőségi fa építése      
Állapotinformációk olvasása... Kész
A következő csomagok automatikusan lettek telepítve, és már nincs rájuk szükség:
  gnome-video-effects python3-brlapi python3-louis python3-pyatspi
  python3-speechd xbrlapi
Ezeket az „sudo apt autoremove” paranccsal törölheti.
A következő további csomagok lesznek telepítve:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr liba52-0.7.4 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libmad0
  libmp3lame0 libmpeg2-4 libmpg123-0 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0
  libsidplay1v5 libtwolame0 libx264-148
Javasolt csomagok:
  libdvdcss2 sidplay-base
Az alábbi ÚJ csomagok lesznek telepítve:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr liba52-0.7.4
  libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libmad0 libmp3lame0 libmpeg2-4 libmpg123-0
  libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libsidplay1v5 libtwolame0 libx264-148
0 frissített, 14 újonnan telepített, 0 eltávolítandó és 387 nem frissített.
1 nincs teljesen telepítve/eltávolítva.
Letöltendő adatmennyiség: 0 B/1.592 kB.
A művelet után 5.479 kB lemezterület kerül felhasználásra.
Folytatni akarja? [I/n] i
Beállítás: util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99runmbbservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runmbbservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service runmbbservice if started
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service cups-browsed at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service runmbbservice at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alfolyamat 1 hibakóddal kilépett
Hibák történtek a feldolgozáskor:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is this and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Try (very carefully) to remove insserv: `sudo apt remove insserv`. If that goes well (i.e. doesn't warn you about doing something harmful), retry the above install.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/284708
It could be because of the software you installed for your huawei data card.